# Spring Boot 2.5.7 with JDK17 with Oracle: Maven tests fail due to missing "java.sql.Date"

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

While upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5.7 with Oracle DB and JDK 17, I get this weird error when running tests from **Maven**.

> The error is: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project kkd: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date: java.sql.Date -> [Help 1]

**When running from Intelli-J IDE, all goes well**. I did not install any libraries or packages outside Maven.

**Anybody** succeeded in running Maven / Surefire unit tests with Oracle and Spring Boot 2.5.5 and JDK 17?

The error gives a hint to the database. Spring JPA etc have no seperate version numbers; they are taken from the spring boot parent.

This was the best Oracle library I found:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
    <version>21.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The maven version is:

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T21:00:29+02:00)
Maven home: C:\development\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\jre
```

What is $JAVA_HOME? When I installed JDK17 on another computer, it had JAVA_HOME set. On this computer apparently not.

```
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot
```

The stacktrace (which was requested) is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project kkd: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date: java.sql.Date -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project kkd: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray (ReflectionUtils.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeGetter (ReflectionUtils.java:72)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.getSuites (ProviderFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.getSuitesIterator (ForkStarter.java:615)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkOnceMultiple (ForkStarter.java:268)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1026)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3402)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive (Class.java:3543)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0 (Class.java:3529)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:2225)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly (JUnit3TestChecker.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test (JUnit3TestChecker.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept (JUnit3TestChecker.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept (JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter (DefaultScanResult.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath (JUnit4Provider.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.getSuites (JUnit4Provider.java:305)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray (ReflectionUtils.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeGetter (ReflectionUtils.java:72)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.getSuites (ProviderFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.getSuitesIterator (ForkStarter.java:615)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkOnceMultiple (ForkStarter.java:268)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1026)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Date
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader.loadClass (IsolatedClassLoader.java:97)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3402)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive (Class.java:3543)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0 (Class.java:3529)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:2225)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly (JUnit3TestChecker.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test (JUnit3TestChecker.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept (JUnit3TestChecker.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept (JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter (DefaultScanResult.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath (JUnit4Provider.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.getSuites (JUnit4Provider.java:305)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray (ReflectionUtils.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeGetter (ReflectionUtils.java:72)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.getSuites (ProviderFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.getSuitesIterator (ForkStarter.java:615)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkOnceMultiple (ForkStarter.java:268)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1026)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is a standard java class. It should be present. please show the complete stacktrace [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html)

Comment: What is the output of mvn —version?

Comment: Is this very old code? On Java 17 and also long before you should not use the `java.sql.Date` class. Use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API out and built-in since Java 8.

Comment: Do other tests run fine? Also tests using other classes from `java.sql.*`? You may also want to share your full pom file.

Comment: This is NOT java.utils.Date, but java.sql.Date. So the database part. It works fine when I test with Intelli-J. When starting to test, it immediately stops with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JDK17 on the System PATH runs everything smoothly!

After installing JDK17, I have to find out what reset the System PATH to Java8.